# continuity and differentiability of $f(x)=\int^{1}_{0}|x-t|tdt$

Tags: calculus

> Finding continuity and differentiability for $$f(x)=\int^{1}_{0}|x-t|tdt$$

What i try:

$\displaystyle f(x)=\int^{x}_{0}(x-t)tdt+\int^{1}_{x}(t-x)dt$

$\displaystyle =\bigg(\frac{xt^2}{2}-\frac{t^3}{3}\bigg)\bigg|^{x}_{0}+\bigg(\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{xt^2}{2}\bigg)\bigg|^{1}_{x}$

$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{6}\bigg(2x^3-3x+2\bigg)$

Because $f(x)$ is a polynomial function of degree three. So it is continuous and differentiable for all real $x$

But answer given as

Function continuous for all real $x$ but not differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Whats wrong with my solution. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: What happens at $x = 2$? Your formula doesn’t hold anymore. What about $x = -1$?

Comment: Here domain $0\leq t<1$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @user when we put $x=2$. Then $\displaystyle f(x)=\int^{1}_{0}|2-t|tdt$. Which is continuous in $t\in[0,1)$

Comment: notice that the integral is always positive. But your $f$ takes negatives values.

Comment: Yes you are right. Then How do i solve it.can u please explain me. Thanks

Comment: splitting the interval to evaluate the absolute value is the correct way. just take care if $x < 0$ or $1 < x$.

Comment: @jacky well yes, the integrand is continuous in $t$, but that isn’t the question. It is whether your function $f(x)$ is continuous in $x$. And for $x=2$ the formula you have given does not give the value of $f(x)$. That formula only holds for $0\le x \le 1$.

Comment: $f$ is differentiable everywhere. While out of scope for this question, differentiability follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement.

Comment: @copper.hat how do you apply that theorem? The integrand is not differentiable for all $x$.

Comment: @lcv You are correct, I need a better reference. It follows from non differentiable analysis but that is much bigger guns than I intended.

Comment: @copper.hat I suppose we can remove an arbitrary small neighborhood of $x=t$ and use the fact that there the derivative of abs is sign.

Comment: @lcv if you want to know why you are allowed to differentiate under the integral sign here, I post an answer with a variant of the theorem.

Comment: @user251257 yes Lipschitz does the trick. Cool, +1

Answer (score 2):

One way is to consider three cases $x \le 0$, $x \in (0,1)$
and
$x \ge 1$ and compute $f$ for each case. Then check that the right and left hand values agree for the functions and their derivatives at $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Let $g_1(x)={1 \over 6}(2-3x)$, $g_2(x)= {1\over 6}(2x^3-3x+2)$ and
$g_3(x)= -g_1(x)$.

If $x\le 0$ then $f(x) = g_1(x)$.

If $x \in (0,1)$ then $f(x) = g_2(x)$.

If $x \ge 1$ then $f(x) = g_3(x)$.

It is straightforward to check that $g_1(0) = g_2(0) = {1 \over 3}$ and $g_2(1) = g_3(1)= {1 \over 6}$ and so $f$ is continuous.

It is straightforward to check that $g_1'(0) = g_2'(0) = -{1 \over 2}$ and $g_2'(1) = g_3'(1) = {1 \over 2}$ and so $f'$ is differentiable.

Comment: Thanks Copperhat. Is it not for $x<0$ or for $x>1$ Here $$f(x)=\int^{1}_{0}|x-t|tdt=\int^{1}_{0}(x-t)\cdot tdt=\frac{3x-2}{6}.$$

Comment: That only works for $x \ge 1$.

Comment: I did not understand why this is wrong. Like when we put $x=-1$. Then $\displaystyle |-1-t|=|1+t|=1+t.$ for $0\leq t<1$ means $|x-t|=x-t$

Comment: Thanks copperhat got it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to differentiate under the integral sign. I am just curious. It is not necessary for such easy integral. In fact, I prefer the direct solution in this case.

Assume:

1. $g:\mathbb R\times [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is measurable,
2. $g(x,\cdot)$ is integrable for every $x\in \mathbb R$,
3. $g(\cdot, t)$ admits a common Lipschitz constant $L$ for almost every $t\in[0,1]$, and
4. $g(\cdot, t)$ is partially differentiable in the first argument at some  $a\in\mathbb R$ for almost every $t\in [0,1]$.

We want to prove that

> $f(x) = \int_0^1 g(x, t) dt$ is differentiable at $a$.

We have
$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = \lim_{x\to a} \int_0^1 \frac{g(x, t) - g(a, t)}{x - a} dt. $$
As the integrand on the right-hand-side is bounded by the Lipschitz constant $L$ almost everywhere, the dominated convergence theorem applies, and we can push the limit operator under the integral sign.
It follows
$$ f'(x) = \int_{0}^1 \frac\partial{\partial x} g(a, t). $$

Obviously, for $g(x, t) = |x-t|$ all the assumptions are met.

*Aside:* You can even replace assumption 3 with a more complicate but weaker assumption: There is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that
$$ \sup_{x\in (a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)} \left| \frac{g(x, t) - g(a, t)}{x - t} \right| $$
is integrable on $[0, 1]$.